# passing boto3.client instance to celery tasks raises JSON serialization error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, celery, boto3

I have a method that I am trying to call as a celery task:

```
@app.task
def launch_compute_node(client, timeout=20, wait_interval=5):

try:
    status = client.run_instances(
        InstanceType='t2.micro',
        MinCount=1,
        MaxCount=1,
        ImageId=XXXXXXX,
        KeyName=KEY_NAME,
        SecurityGroupIds=[XXXXXXX, XXXXXXXX],
        SubnetId=SUBNET_ID,
        PrivateIpAddress=XXXXXXX,
        TagSpecifications=[
        {'ResourceType': 'instance', 
            'Tags': [
             {'Key': 'Name', 
            'Value': NODE_NAME}]}]
    )
except ClientError as ex:
    logger.error(str(ex))
    return None

state = get_instance_state(status)
instance_id = status['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
counter = timeout

while state != 'running':
    logger.debug('Instance not in running state, waiting...')
    time.sleep(wait_interval)   # sleep `wait_interval' seconds
    counter = counter - 1
    if counter <= 0:
        logger.warning('Timed out after %s attempts' % timeout)
        # TODO: Probably it's a good idea do terminate the failed instance here.
        return None

    status = client.describe_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])
    state = get_instance_state(status['Reservations'][0])
    instance_id = status['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
    logger.debug('Instance \'%s\' in state \'%s\'' % (instance_id, state))

logger.info('Instance \'%s\' ready for jobs' % instance_id)

return instance_id
```

A perfectly sound method but when I create a celery task I get:

`kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: <botocore.client.EC2 object at 0x106113438> is not JSON serializable`

Which makes sense -- no reason why a boto EC2 client should be JSON serializable.  But this leaves me in a bind -- without significantly overhauling the code, how can I create and check the state of an EC2 instance from a celery task?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

By default every message to the broker in celery are encoded to JSON. [Kombu is responsible for the serialization of these messages](http://docs.celeryproject.org/projects/kombu/en/latest/userguide/serialization.html).

In your case, you are trying to send a botocore.client.EC2 object and Kombu tries to serialize that in order to make a proper AMQP message that is stored by the broker and fed to celery.
However, JSON can [serialize only a limited set](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders) of types by default. Since JSON doesn't know how to serialize your object this error is thrown.

My guess would be that the problem happens when you return the instance_id. What happens when you return nothing instead?

[This article](http://oddbird.net/2017/03/20/serializing-things/) for serializing Django tasks might be useful to you.

Comment: This makes sense.  I have opted to use a simpler task to call the launch_compute_node method.  Thanks for the link